# What does this extend do?

Tags: ruby

Given this example:

```
module A
  module B
    def foo
      puts 'foo'
    end

    extend A::B
  end
end
```

What does this `extend A::B` do?

Comment: More often you see this written as `extend self`. When working with classes the equivalent is `class << self   def foo .. end  end`

Comment: @kimmmo Good point about `extend self` but we should be careful: https://gist.github.com/nedzadarek/e651c16b6e768b8f30df Well, juanitofatas can check that too.

Comment: Do you want to know about the differences of: `extend A::B`, `extend B`, `extend self`, `extend ::A::B`? I think you wanted to know about the first 2 examples I mentioned but I am not sure. If http://stackoverflow.com/a/24299513/2597260 answer is not sufficient, and you want above informations I will write something.

Comment: @DarekNędza Thanks for your kind offer. I think huocp is quite good for now. Thanks for the links, really appreciated.

Comment: `def self.foo` also works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It extends module A::B with itself, essentially make method `foo` available on module object `A::B` itself.

Without that line, you are not able to call `A::B.foo` in your code.

You may want to read more on Ruby `extend aModule` vs `include aModule`.